# What is the scsi id of iscsi initiator?

Tags: linux, scsi, iscsi

I created two iscsi targets on the same block device. And connected to the two targets with two initiators.

I wanted to maintain these two initiators with Multipath, but they are considered as two different devices because their scsi IDs are different.

So I am wondering how the scsi id of a iscsi initiator is decided and can I change it?

Comment: Multipath shouldn't care about the initiator ID.  And, as Andy hinted at, they're going to be the same anyway.  It's possible that whatever you're using for an iSCSI target has invented different SCSI ID's for your block device in each target.  If you're using a virtualized block device, it may not even have a SCSI ID of its own - hence the target software coming up with an ID for it.

Comment: Yes, I am using a virtualized block device, but is there a way to let multipath think those two initiators are the save device ?

Answer (score 0):

The iscsi initiator name is specified in /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi

Comment: Yes, that is the initiator name, but what multipath takes as wwid is in /dev/disk/by-id/